# Interactive latex slider

Tags: tikz-pgf

Please, how do I make the slider(s) in the link below interactive or draggable?:

[Sliders in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/181319/sliders-in-latex/181334#181334)

Comment: What do you mean interactive? What do you expect from them? Just to be draggable or to change something in the document as you move them?

Comment: @Kofi What have you tried so far? and Welcome to TeX.SE

Comment: @Superuser27 please, I want the slider to be draggable.

Comment: @Kofi I am voting to close this questions because, to my knowledge, this interactive behavior is attained via pdf viewers only and TeX can only create documents compatible for one such. For a start, please see here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45106/how-to-make-interactive-pdf-documents-with-tex

Comment: @Kofi What effect should the slider have?

Comment: @samcarter from What I understood from OP's question is that OP needs a slider that will act as a slider you can see for example in a vlc player `;)`

Comment: @Raaja This is also how I understand the question, but what should the slider influence?

Comment: @samcarter I really don't know that part.

Comment: @Raaja Me neither, that's why I asked

Comment: @samcarter May be we should wait for the OP to explain us a bit.

Comment: @Raaja I totally agree, that's why I voted to leave open

Comment: @Raaja I think the OP wants a movable slider.

Comment: @JouleV Yes, that's clear. But what should the moveable slider do?

Comment: The slider could show the number of votes for closing a "do this for me" question , I would move it 1 % to the end

Comment: @samcarter [This slider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jxX9.png), for example. I'm sorry for my bad English, but I can't find an appropriate word to describe this.

Comment: @JouleV This shows what a slider looks like, but the big question is what should it do? Should it move the page up and down like the one you show in your image? Should it do something else? Control the input of some form? Control the appearance of some animation?

Comment: @samcarter Well let's wait the response from the OP then :)

Comment: My main concern has to do with a two column table with a slider below that can be moved from one end to the other. Thank you